# CodeIgniter and Google charts - dropdown based on mysql values

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, google-visualization, codeigniter-3

I am using code igniter, google charts with php and MySQL to display charts. It works using fixed query. I am trying to add a dropdown to display the chart based on the option (sql column "status") selected
Here is what I have so far. How can I modify this to accept dropdown values?

model.php

```
public function get_chart_data()  
{
    $query = $this->db->get($this->db_mgmt);
    $this->db->select('rating, COUNT(rating) AS Count');
    $this->db->from('db_mgmt');
    $this->db->where('status =', $status);
    $this->db->group_by('rating'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results['chart'] = $query->result();
}
```

controller.php

```
$this->load->model('model', 'chart');
public function index() {
        $results = $this->chart->get_chart_data();
        $data['chart'] = $results['chart'];
        $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
}
```

view.php

```
<?php 
foreach ($chart as $object) {
$open_all[] = "['".$object->rating."', ".$object->Count."]";
}
?>

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_open);

   function drawChart_open() {
    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Rating');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
    data.addRows([
    <?php echo implode(",", $open_all);?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('open_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }

  <div id="open_div" class="chart"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the below using ajax but it doesn't seem to work. I am definitely sure I am doing something wrong here but not sure where. Using Inspect in chrome also doesn't give any errors.

model.php

```
public function fetch_result($status)  
  {
    $query = $this->db->get($this->db_mgmt);
    $this->db->select('rating, COUNT(status) AS Status_Count');
    $this->db->from('db__mgmt');
    $this->db->where('status =', $status);
    $this->db->group_by('rating'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
  }
```

controller.php

```
$this->load->model('model', 'chart');
public function mychart() {

if(!empty($_POST["val"])) {
    $val=$_POST["val"];
    $result_new=$this->chart->fetch_result($val);

    $array = array();
    $cols = array();
    $rows = array();
    $cols[] = array("id"=>"","label"=>" Rating","pattern"=>"","type"=>"string");
    $cols[] = array("id"=>"","label"=>"Count","pattern"=>"","type"=>"number");  

    foreach ($result_new as $object) {
      $rows[] = array("c"=>array(array("v"=>$object->risk_rating,"f"=>null),array("v"=>(int)$object->Status_Count,"f"=>null)));
   }

    $array = array("cols"=>$cols,"rows"=>$rows);
    echo json_encode($array);

    }

}
```

view.php

```
function drawChart_open_all(num) {         
    var PieChartData = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/chart/mychart",
    data:'val='+num,
    dataType:"json"
    }).responseText;

    alert(PieChartData);


    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(PieChartData);
    var options = {
              pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage',       
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('open_new'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }

<div><span> <b>Pie Chart<br /><br /></span></div>
<form>
  <select name="status" onchange="drawChart_open_all(this.value)">
<option value="WIP">WIP</option>
<option value="Close">Close</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="open_new" class="chart"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: might be easier to use a [Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboard) in combination with a [CategoryFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter) -- let google handle the filtering...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks a lot for the solution it works great. Additionally I wanted to ask what if I did want to send the value to run a different function in model.php and display on the same chart? For example, if the time was changed, I wanted to call a different MySQL query on the same table that would return a different set of values for the same columns.

Comment: not much on php, i would use ajax from javascript -- but seems like you could send a get request -- or if the data isn't massive, include more and throw in a DateRangeFilter...

Comment: @WhiteHat I have tried with ajax (updated the question) but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: sorry, not exactly what I had in mind -- take a look at my answer -- i'll try to help but not much experience with PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what the problem was and used ajax in the end. @WhiteHat solution led to also in the right direction. Thanks for that!

model.php

```
public function fetch_result($status)  
  {
    $query = $this->db->get($this->db_mgmt);
    $this->db->select('rating, COUNT(status) AS status_count');
    $this->db->from('db_mgmt');
    $this->db->where('status =', $status);
    $this->db->group_by('rating'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $results_new = $query->result();  // <-- Forgot to add this!
    return $results_new;
  }
```

controller.php

```
$this->load->model('model', 'chart');

public function mychart() {

if(!empty($_POST['option'])) {     

$val = $_POST['option'];            
$result_new=$this->chart->fetch_result($val);

$array = array();
$cols = array();
$rows = array();
$cols[] = array("id"=>"","label"=>" Rating","pattern"=>"","type"=>"string");
$cols[] = array("id"=>"","label"=>"Count","pattern"=>"","type"=>"number");  

foreach ($result_new as $object) {
  $rows[] = array("c"=>array(array("v"=>(string)$object->rating),array("v"=>(int)$object->status_count)));
}

$array = array("cols"=>$cols,"rows"=>$rows);
echo json_encode($array);

}
}
```

view.php

```
   function drawChart_open_all(status) {

    var PieChartData = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/chart/mychart",
    data: { 'option':status },  // <-- kept as option instead of val
    dataType:"json",
    global: false,              // <-- Added 
    async:false,                // <-- Added 
    success: function(data){    // <-- Added 
    return data;                // <-- Added 
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
    }).responseText;

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(PieChartData);
    var options = {  pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage', };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('open_new'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

<div><span> <b>Pie Chart<br /><br /></span></div>
<form>
<select name="status" onchange="drawChart_open_all(this.value)">
<option value="WIP">WIP</option>
<option value="Close">Close</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="open_new" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the easiest thing would be to send a GET request with the `<option>` value

First, go back to your first version.

Next, send the value in your `onchange` event

```
function drawChart_open_all(num) {
  location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/chart/mychart?option=" + num;
}
```

Then in Model --
`get_chart_data()`

you should be able to access the value with --
`$_GET['option']`

use that to modify your query

here's an old answer with similar concept -- difference is it uses POST vs. GET
and a `<form>` with a `<input type="submit">` button to send the request
[How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917626/5090771)

Comment: hope this helps, you could use `ajax` to make the call, rather than using `location = ...` -- but I think that would require more work...